# Configuration of schema.xml for nutch and solr

Tags: solr, typo3, nutch

I have a question in connection with the configuration of nutch and solr. Do I have to name the _default directory in solr, nutch and do I have to mark the head of the schema.xml file as nutch or can I give any name for it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nutch itself doesn't use the `schema.xml` file](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/a48a9f6f2045a908c6dff275a726fadd079fc6ad/src/plugin/indexer-solr/README.md#schemaxml), it is provided as a base schema.xml to use in Solr (or as an example detailing which fields need to be added to your own schema). The `name` property of the `schema.xml` doesn't have to be `nutch` it is provided just as an indication that the configuration is related to the operation of Nutch. Keep in mind that this file is only relevant to Solr's configuration.